# System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo Stop Rounding Number

Tags: c#, rounding

I'm using `System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo` class to format my numbers using the following code.

```
int decimalDigits = 4;
NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
format.CurrencyDecimalDigits = decimalDigits;
format.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
format.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
format.CurrencySymbol = "";

string value = amount.ToString("C", format);
```

The above code format the number fine but I have a problem of rounding.

Lets say I entered amount `12345.12345`, Now The value I want is `12,345.1234`
but it returns `12,345.1235`.

So basically I want to stop rounding, I searched over the Internet but could not find what Im looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Format` will round floating point values when formatting so you need to apply your own "rounding rule" before formatting the value. My understanding is that you want to truncate the value.

When using `Math.Round` to round a value you can specify the precision. However, when truncating using `Math.Truncate` you have no such option. Instead you have to multiply and divide by 10 to the power of your precision (in your case 10,000):

```
var factor = Math.Pow(10, decimalDigits);
var truncatedAmount = Math.Truncate(factor*amount)/factor;
string value = truncatedAmount.ToString("C", format);
```

This will produce the desired output `12.345.1234`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is here:

```
amount = Math.Floor(amount * Math.Pow(10, decimalDigits)) / Math.Pow(10, decimalDigits);
```

Before using

```
string value = amount.ToString("C", format);
```